# Laravel run the queue job every second

Tags: laravel, queue

I have created a queue job which need to run every second.How can I do that ? So i have created a job using `artisan` command,but the job is not run every second. I think I need to reconfigure some config files of supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel docs have examples of exactly that. check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#supervisor-configuration

The default examples is

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/yourproject/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile= /var/www/html/yourproject/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Note that you need to have a worker connection set in `config/queues.php`, and then on superviser, in the command `artisan queue:work` you can specify the connection. in the example i sent is using sqs but you can configure other stuff like redis

Comment: thanks for reply. I am getting spawn error after runing sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:* . Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm successfully using [Spatie's Short Schedule](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-short-schedule) package for this.

Answer (score -1):

You may use crontab for your queueable job. But Cron only allows for a minimum of one minute. Use `crontab -e` to set your schedule with the help of https://crontab.guru/ add this  `2 * * * * php /var/www/html/your-project-folder/artisan queue:work >> /dev/null 2>&1` to your `crontab -e` which runs every 2 minutes.

What you could, you need to write a shell script with an infinite loop that runs your task, and then sleeps for every second.